# Remove numbers and brackets from varchar field result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to remove brackets and numbers from current result set. BenefitCode is a varchar field.

```
select BenefitCode
from uwc
```

current output,

```
[70] PRESCRIPTION DRUGS
[593] GLOBAL PAYMENT- HOSPITAL, PHYSICIAN/ SURGEON AND OTHER CHARGES
```

desired output,

```
 PRESCRIPTION DRUGS
 GLOBAL PAYMENT- HOSPITAL, PHYSICIAN/ SURGEON AND OTHER CHARGES
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `stuff()`:

```
select stuff(BenefitCode, 1, charindex(']', BenefitCode) + 1, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Gordan's answer, you could do this by using the substring function.

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING(BenefitCode, charindex(' ', BenefitCode)+1, len(BenefitCode))
FROM    uwc
```

Comment: The charindex(' ', BenefitCode) assumes that the first space will occur after the brackets and numbers, btw. Will have to be revised if that is not the case.